# How do I change a file with link contents into an actual link in git?

Tags: git, symlink, mode

I received a code drop outside of git and have added it to my repository. However, the drop came from a machine that doesn't support symlinks. As a result, there are files that were originally links that now are treated as a file whose contents are a single path equivalent to what the original link pointed to. They are stored in git as a normal file.

I'd like to change them to actual links in git.

In other words, I'd like to change their mode to 120000 (and do nothing else) and commit them.

What is the git command to do that?

Comment: _I'd like to change their mode to 120000 (and do nothing else)_  No, you **need** to do something else, namely replacing the contents of the file. A symlink contains the path to the target, a copy contains (a copy of) the contents. So what you need to do is to correct the files in the Unix filesystem without the need of thinking of git. About the mode you don't have to worry, git will do it automatically. You can just `git commit -a` after ỳou made the changes in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, for example, a file called `somefile` that was a symlink pointing to `/opt/somewhere/somefile` got turned into a text file with content "/opt/somewhere/somefile" ? And now you want to restore the original symlink?

I don't know if there's a git command for that. I think you'd have to manually replace the file with a symlink and commit it:

```
filepath=somefile
linkpath=$(cat $filepath)
ln -sf $linkpath $filepath
git commit $filepath
```